# array declaration, and not using mid-index

Tags: c, arrays

i want using array not continuous index.

```
int arr[30];
```

and using

```
arr[1]=x;
arr[2]=y;
arr[30]=z;
```

then **arr[3]~arr[29]** are unused, consume unnecessary memory space.

is there any method not assign memory for arr[3]~arr[29] ?

Comment: You implement like map.

Comment: another way is [sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). But it depends on specifically what you want to do to choose the most appropriate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in arrays that C provides simply do not do that which you ask.

You can write code for managing some data structure that does that, such as a hash table, but the compiler won't do it for you.

Also, for the record, since you declared `arr` to be of length 30, `arr[30]=z` is an invalid operation. Indices are zero-based, so only 0-29 are valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the following statement, the amount of memory allocation is determined:

`int arr[30];`

This statement basically instructs the run time to procure contiguous memory for 30 integers. If you are concerned about the memory, decrease the size of the array at the time of declaration or use a linked list.